# Does using $this instead of $(this) provide a performance enhancement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, this

Assume I have the following example:

**Example One**

```
$('.my_Selector_Selected_More_Than_One_Element').each(function() {
    $(this).stuff();
    $(this).moreStuff();
    $(this).otherStuff();
    $(this).herStuff();
    $(this).myStuff();
    $(this).theirStuff();
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        howMuchStuff();
    });
    $(this).tooMuchStuff();
    // Plus just some regular stuff
    $(this).css('display','none');
    $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
    $(this).has('.hisBabiesStuff').css('color','light blue');
    $(this).has('.herBabiesStuff').css('color','pink');
}
```

Now, it could be:

**Example Two**

```
$('.my_Selector_Selected_More_Than_One_Element').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.stuff();
    $this.moreStuff();
    $this.otherStuff();
    $this.herStuff();
    $this.myStuff();
    $this.theirStuff();
    $this.children().each(function(){
        howMuchStuff();
    });
    $this.tooMuchStuff();
    // Plus just some regular stuff
    $this.css('display','none');
    $this.css('font-weight','bold');
    $this.has('.hisBabiesStuff').css('color','light blue');
    $this.has('.herBabiesStuff').css('color','pink');
}
```

The point isn't the actual code, but the use of `$(this)` when it is used more than once/twice/three times or more.

Am I better off performance-wise using **example two** than **example one** (maybe with an explanation why or why not)?

**EDIT/NOTE**

I suspect that two is better one; what I was a little fearful of was peppering my code with `$this` and than inadvertently introducing a potentially difficult-to-diagnosis bug when I inevitably  forget to add the `$this` to an event handler. So should I use `var $this = $(this)`, or `$this = $(this)` for this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

As Scott points out below, this is considered caching in jQuery.

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/caching-in-jquery.html

Jared

Comment: About that answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623592/safe-dynamic-include-from-get/7623610#7623610) (deleted now): I wanted to hack that server :p

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, definitely use `$this`.

A new jQuery object must be constructed each time you use `$(this)`, while `$this` keeps the same object for reuse.

---

A [performance test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-this-vs-this) shows that `$(this)` is *significantly* slower than `$this`. However, as both are performing millions of operations a second, it is unlikely either will have any real impact, but it is better practice to reuse jQuery objects anyway. Where *real* performance impacts arise is when a selector, rather than a DOM object, is repeatedly passed to the jQuery constructor - e.g. `$('p')`.

---

As for the use of `var`, again **always** use `var` to declare new variables. By doing so, the variable will only be accessible in the *function* it is declared in, and will not conflict with other functions.

---

Even better, jQuery is designed to be used with chaining, so take advantage of this where possible. Instead of declaring a variable and calling functions on it multiple times:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.addClass('aClass');
$this.text('Hello');
```

...chain the functions together to make the use of an additional variable unecessary:

```
$(this).addClass('aClass').text('Hello');
```

Comment: also declare `$this` as `var $this` so that `$this` is contained within the `each()` scope and not in the default global scope

Comment: @mdmullinax - I just added a note asking for that very same clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Bang on, I wish I could vote twice. The edit was the icing on the cake.

Comment: @Jared, added some further notes regarding your clarification question.

Comment: @Box9 - That performance test is very interesting. On chaining, does it provide a performance enhancement from just using `$this` instead?

Comment: @Jared, technically yes, as there is no need for variable lookup, but this is extremely insignificant unless the variable is many scopes up (i.e. in an outer function). The reason for using chaining is typically for cleaner-looking code, however it does also reduce your filesize.

Comment: @Box9 - And see in many cases I think the opposite, that it's harder to discern horizontally versus vertically. I used to chain like a drunken sailor curses, but just got to where I thought it was difficult to read. This is just my opinion.

Comment: @Jared, it's just a matter of preference. I do think the overwhelming preference is to chain though, so you may want to get used to it if working with others ;)

Comment: @Box9 - I'm not saying I don't chain, I just don't go out of my to organize my code so it takes advantage of it 100% of the time. I'll do chains two - three concats deep, but usually stop there (and rarely need more than that, in my experience).

Comment: @Box9 - I've seen some that chained 9, 10, 11 methods in a row. Maybe that's why I twitch a little when I hear the word chaining...

Comment: A [performance](http://jsfiddle.net/hnAft/1/) test on jsfiddle shows a difference as well, although much smaller than the difference shown by the test linked here. Any idea what would explain the differences?

In any case, the differences are reasonably marginal, even in a contrived test like this. So, use `$(this)` once, but don't be super paranoid about performance if you have to use it twice (e.g. don't try to cache it globally or something)

Comment: @crazy2be, the smaller difference is because `addClass()` and `removeClass()` are relatively expensive operations. More time is being spent on these in proportion to accessing `$(this)` or `$this`, shadowing the real difference between them.

Answer (score 3):

Go to a page with jQuery and run this in your console. I know it's awful but you can see that $this wins out every time.

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hello');
  $(this).removeClass('hello');
  $(this).addClass('hello');
  $(this).removeClass('hello');
  $(this).addClass('hello');
  $(this).removeClass('hello');
  $(this).addClass('hello');
  $(this).removeClass('hello');
  $(this).addClass('hello');
  $(this).removeClass('hello');
  $(this).addClass('hello');
  $(this).removeClass('hello');
  $(this).addClass('hello');
  $(this).removeClass('hello');
});
var now = new Date().getTime();
console.log(now- time);

var var_time = new Date().getTime();
$('div').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass('hello');
  $this.removeClass('hello');
  $this.addClass('hello');
  $this.removeClass('hello');
  $this.addClass('hello');
  $this.removeClass('hello');
  $this.addClass('hello');
  $this.removeClass('hello');
  $this.addClass('hello');
  $this.removeClass('hello');
  $this.addClass('hello');
  $this.removeClass('hello');
  $this.addClass('hello');
  $this.removeClass('hello');
});
var var_now = new Date().getTime();
console.log(var_now - var_time);
```

Comment: A modified version of what you have above: [Careful this might slow your browser down](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/evuub/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are making a reference to $(this) multiple times you should store it in a variable. $this is just a convention to let others know that $this represents a jquery object.

This is even more important if your jquery object was created with a complex selector.

Also, in your pseudocode example you can generally make use of chaining on $(this).

Example:

```
$(this).addClass("someclass").css({"color": "red"});
```

Answer (score 2):

@Box9 is totally on point.  I can't tell you how many times I have to refactor jQuery b/c people don't use caching.

I would also add that combined with caching that people need to learn to do this:

```
var $element = $("#elementId"),
    elementLength = $element.length,
    elementText = $element.text(),
    someString = "someValue",
    someInt = 0,
    someObj = null;
```

instead of this:

```
var $element = $("#elementId");
var elementLength = $element.length;
var elementText = $element.text();
var someString = "someValue";
var someInt = 0;
var someObj = null;
```

Comment: When you say caching, do you mean Box9's chaining example? Also, why would not having a `var` declaration before each be a performance enhancement? (I think the former is hard to discern)

Comment: @Jared Farrish - [Caching from jQuery's blog](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/caching-in-jquery.html)

Comment: @Jared Farrish - [More ways to optimize jQuery via Net Tuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/)

Comment: @Scott - Oh ok, the `$this` issue is considered caching (I would have called it a stored reference, didn't make the jump to caching). You didn't answer the question on the use of multiple `var`'s.

Comment: @Jared, the `var` thing is more about style. It makes the code look cleaner to some, and to others (e.g. Douglas Crockford), it is important to ensure there's only one `var` per function.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - I wouldn't really call it optimizing the code, to most it's preference, but I would say that you DO save bytes by not retyping var over and over.  Secondly, since there's just function scope, you might as well put everything at the top and use one single var declaration.

Comment: @Box9, Scott - It's more of a white-space/visual balance thing to me, like trying to space out the colons in CSS so they all line up (which I think is silly and harder to read too). It's just easier for me to visually scan for var keywords, but I guess that's just what I'm used to.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Yea, for me, I'm OCD about my code.  I have to have everything line up perfectly.  Correct spacing, tabbing, extra lines to make it very readable.  Obviously this is all for dev.  Once it goes live it's all minified, but still.

Comment: @Scott - I work at a university and have had students work for me who were computer and BCIS majors. I didn't study programming at a university (I'm just self-taught, going on seven years PHP and JS), so I didn't have a heavy-handed instructor beating their preferences into me (I've known a few who went through F-for-formatting threats). I've just learned through experience and some truly awful dog-lunch formatting what I think works. I tell them to be flexible, since it always changes and use what works/is expected. Like you said, it all disappears into the compiler/minifiers maw anyway.

Comment: @Jared Farrish -  No problem and I'm the same way.  I didn't go to college or certification schools.  I taught myself everything I know through communities such as this, books, and picking the brain of those smarter than me.  I'm day one ASP.NET guy and have, within the last couple years, started to more and more things to client-side with the advent of the jQuery framework and Page/Web Methods.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - With respect to code formatting, all I would add is that when you work in an environment where multiple people are editing code, it really really matters.  I probably waste more time optimizing bad code and badly formatted code, just for the benefit of others that have to work on it.

Comment: @Scott - Sure, I understand that. I've never really worked in a group where we had to coordinate our coding styles to match, but that would be important. That's why I usually preach flexibility and having an open mind. I'm certainly more likely to be open to formatting now than I used to, although some really make me cringe.