# Selectors and performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

Is there any benefit to performance when I do the following in Mootools (or any framework, really)?:

```
var elem = $('#elemId');    
elem.addClass('someClass');        
elem.set('some attribute', 'some value');
```

etc, etc. Basically, I'm updating certain elements a lot on the DOM and I was wondering if creating a variable in memory and using that when needed was better than:

```
$('#elemId').addClass('someClass');    
$('#elemId').set('some attribute', 'some value');
```

The changes to `$('#elemId')` are all over the place, in various different functions.

Comment: I live by a simple rule: if any selector is to be called repeatedly (or even twice), cache it into a __scoped__ variable. This includes check for existence like `var foo = $("foo"); if (foo) foo.doSomething();` I would not export every single selector call to the global object, though. The cost of that vs the relatively fast selector speeds cannot always be justified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spencer ,

This is called caching and it is one of the best practices.

when you say

```
$('#elemId');
```

It will go and query the DOM everytime , so if you say

```
var elem = $('#elemId');
```

elem acts as a cache element and improves performance a lot.

This is manly useful in IE as it has memory leaks promblem and all

ready this document which is really good

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/14-helpful-jquery-tricks-notes-and-best-practices/

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you query the dom. Lookups by ID are extremely fast. Second most is css classes. So as long as you're doing it by only a single ID (not a complex selector containing an id), there shouldn't be much of a benefit. However, if you're using any other selector, caching is the way to go.

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS

Comment: Those pages are about performance of _styling_ while this question is about performance of lookup by selector.  Lookups by id are indeed fast.  Lookups by class are about as slow as any other complicated selector that doesn't involve combinators.

Comment: I disagree. These documents directly speak of css selector performance and efficiency. They just back up my claim that, other than ID queries, caching should be employed.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: Yes, but they speak of selector performance and efficiency in the context of styling (which involves finding all the selectors that match a given element), not in the context of using selectors the way jQuery does (which involves finding all elements that match a given selector).  My point was that all queries of the type jQuery does that don't invovle and id are about equally slow including queries by class.  Oh, and the query by id is only fast because jQuery purposefully breaks it to only return the first element with that id, not all of them like it does for other queries.

Comment: CSS selectors performance are completely different from ones in a javascript selector engine, such as `sizzle` (jquery) or `slick` (mootools). eg, in CSS your rulesets are parsed from [right to left](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/). in a js selector, it's the opposite--the more you narrow down your start node, the faster it becomes and it works from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

You first approach is faster then your second approach, because you "cache" the search on `#elemId`.

Meaning the calls to `addClass` and `set` don't require extra lookups in the DOM for your element.

However! You can link function calls:

```
$('#elemId').addClass('someClass').set('some attribute', 'some value');
```

Depending on your application `caching` or `linking` might work better, but definitely not identical sequential lookups in the same block.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, caching can be as much as 99% faster then using a jQuery object every time. In the case you presented it will not make much difference. if you plan to use the selector many times, you should definitely cache the object as a variable so it doesn't get created everytime you run it.

A similar questions was answered at [Does using $this instead of $(this) provide a performance enhancement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement).

Check performance log http://jsperf.com/jquery-this-vs-this

Answer (score -1):

You are considering using a local variable to cache a value of a potentially slow lookup.

**How slow is the call itself?** If it's fast, caching won't make much a difference. If it's slow, then cache at the first call. Selectors vary significantly in their cost-- just think about how the code must fine the element. If it's an ID, then the browser provides fast access, whereas classes and nodes my require full DOM scans. Check out [profiling of jQuery (Sizzle) selectors](http://jsperf.com/jquery-context-find-class) to get a sense of these.

**Can you chain the calls?** Consider "chaining" method calls where possible. This provides the efficiency without introducing another variable.

For your example, I'd write:

```
$('#elemId').addClass('someClass').set('some attribute', 'some value');
```

**How does the code read?** Usually if the same method is going to be called multiple times, it is clearer to DRY it up, and use a local variable. The reader then understands the intent better-- you don't force them to scan all the jQuery calls to verify that they are the same. BTW, a fairly standard convention is to name jQuery variables starting with a $-- which is legal in Javascript-- as in

```
var $elem = $('#elem');
$elem.addClass('someClass');
```

Hope this helps.