# Optimizing jQuery code

Tags: jquery, optimization

I have a table that lists locations and then allows a user to select 1 or more permissions for that location. I have the following code working that I can select the top row  check-box and you can check all the boxes in that column. I'm looking for tips to optimize what I'm doing. You click on the ".all###" check-box and all the ones with a class of ".XXX" get checked. How can I optimize my jquery? I'm still learning and although I got it to work im sure its not the best route. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my part of my HTML code

```
        <table>
    <colgroup></colgroup>

    <colgroup></colgroup>

    <colgroup></colgroup>

    <colgroup span="5"></colgroup>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="locationCode">Location Code</th>

            <th class="locationName">Name</th>

            <th class="locationAddress">Address</th>

            <th class="selectOption">Admin</th>

            <th class="selectOption">Remote</th>

            <th class="selectOption">Support</th>

            <th class="selectOption">Misc</th>

            <th class="selectOption">Logging</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" class="grayBackground"></th>

            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" class="allAdmin admin"></td>

            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" class="allRemote remote"></td>

            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" class="allSupport support"></td>

            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" class="allMisc misc"></td>

            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" class="allLogging logging"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>VST</td>

            <td>Demo #1</td>

            <td>1 Street, City State</td>

            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" class="admin"></td>

            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" class="remote"></td>

            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" class="support"></td>

            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" class="misc"></td>

            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" class="logging"></td>
        </tr>
```

and my jQuery

```
                $(function() {
                $(".allAdmin").change(function() {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                        $(".admin").prop("checked", true);
                        return;
                    }
                    $(".admin").prop("checked", false);
                });
                $(".allRemote").change(function() {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                        $(".remote").prop("checked", true);
                        return;
                    }
                    $(".remote").prop("checked", false);
                });
                $(".allSupport").change(function() {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                        $(".support").prop("checked", true);
                        return;
                    }
                    $(".support").prop("checked", false);
                });
                $(".allMisc").change(function() {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                        $(".misc").prop("checked", true);
                        return;
                    }
                    $(".misc").prop("checked", false);
                });
                $(".allLogging").change(function() {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                        $(".logging").prop("checked", true);
                        return;
                    }
                    $(".logging").prop("checked", false);
                });
            });
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 classes for each "master" checkbox? `class="allAdmin admin"` would be more understandable as `class="allAdmin"`. I don't think it functionally changes your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit of an overkill optimization, but this code should work:

```
$(function() {
  $('.allAdmin, .allRemote, .allSupport, .allMisc, .allLogging').change(function() {
    $('.' + $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0].substring(3).toLowerCase()).prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

If your elements have only one class (nothing like `<div class="allAdmin anotherClass">`), you can use this slightly shorter version:

```
$(function() {
  $('.allAdmin, .allRemote, .allSupport, .allMisc, .allLogging').change(function() {
    $('.' + $(this).attr('class').substring(3).toLowerCase()).prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you explian this a little? Seems like you look for the change on all the "all" classes, then concatenate a period to get the td class. Then some type of array to ...something...something..something...dark side... Also it works and is only 2 lines, thanks for it.

Comment: Really? I'm amazed that it does. I never tested it. Anyways, since you asked for optimized/compact, I made it hard to read. Basically, it takes the class attribute of the item, splits it by the space (since you can have more than one class, the first one is chosen), and chops off the first four letters with `.substring(3)`. *Then*, that's made lowercase and that whole thing extracts the name of the appropriate child (`.allAdmin` -> `.admin`). That element's check state (checked/unchecked) is then set to that of the object we're working with.

Answer (score 4):

```
var selector = ['.allAdmin', '.allRemote', /* etc */].join(', ');

$(selector).change(function ()
{
    var sel = '.' + this.className.substring(3).toLowerCase();
    $(sel).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

---

It looks like you're trying to use a single checkbox to control a group of checkboxes (warning, shameless self-promotion ahead). If this is the case, there's a jQuery plugin I wrote that will make this much easier for you: http://mjball.github.com/jQuery-CheckAll.

Answer (score 0):

One optimization I see is transforming all your jQuery calls into variables. ie:

```
var logging = $(".logging");
//More code
logging.prop("checked", true);
//etc...
logging.prop("checked", false);
```

This is the same as the difference between "$(this)" and "this" described here: [Does using $this instead of $(this) provide a performance enhancement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement)

Code-wise, you can also use ternaries:

```
$(".allAdmin").change(function() {
    $(".admin").prop("checked",
    ($(".admin").prop("checked") ? true : false); // ((condition) ? do_true : do_false);
});
```