# .append jquery, limit to one character per <span>

Tags: jquery

I have these two functions:

```
jQuery.fn.enterText = function(e){
if( $("#cursor").val() && e.keyCode != 32  ){
    var character = $("#cursor").val();
    $("#cursor").val("");
    this.append("<span class = 'text'>"+character+"</span>");
    $("#cursor").insertAfter(".text:last");
    $("#cursor").focus();

}
};

jQuery.fn.markCursor = function(e){
    $(this).focus();
   $(this).keyup(function(e) {
  $("#cursor-start").enterText(e);

});

};
```

What my problem is that if I text is entered rapidly, some  elements will have more than one character, for example (abc). I wanted to know how to limit to one character in an efficient manner, I thought of using an array, but would that not be too efficient?

Comment: One big improvement would be to use [jQuery caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement). All of your `$("#cursor")` calls are inefficient.

Comment: ya I can see that, but I the "this" in the function doesn't refer to the #cursor element, it refers to "#cursor-start", I attach it like so: $("#cursor-start).markCursor();

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You've got four calls to `$('#cursor')` in your first `enterText` function, which means you're searching the DOM four times. Do something like `var $cursor = $('#cursor');` and use that, and it will only do a DOM search once.

Comment: ohhh I see what you mean, yes that would help :) sorry for not understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
character = character.split("").join("</span><span class='text'>");
this.append("<span class='text'>" + character + "</span>");
```

I recommend changing some JQuery functions in ordinary JavaScript functions: 
`document.getElementById("cursor-start")` is universally supported, so use it instead of `$("#cursor-start")`. Optimized code:

```
jQuery.fn.enterText = function(e){
    var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");
    var character = cursor.value;
    if(character && e.keyCode != 32){
        cursor.value = "";
        character = character.split("").join("</span><span class='text'>");
        this.append("<span class = 'text'>"+character+"</span>");
        $("#cursor").insertAfter(".text:last");
        cursor.focus();
    }

};

jQuery.fn.markCursor = function(e){
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).keyup(function(e) {
        $("#cursor-start").enterText(e);
    });
};
```