# Safe dynamic include from $_GET

Tags: php, security

Is this a safe way to include pages from a $_GET parameter:

```
$pg = basename($_GET['pg']);
if (is_file('views/' . $pg . '.php')) {
  require 'views/' . $pg . '.php';
}
```

I sanitize the parameter using basename() and all the possible files for including are in a "views/" subdirectory. It seems safe, but I want to be sure.

The reason I want to do this, is because I currently use mod_rewrite to define all my URLs, but I want a single point of entry and I'd rather keep defining them that way than use a router. So I'd have a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^item/(\d+)/?$ index.php?pg=item&id=$1 [L, NC]
```

And my index.php would look like this:

```
ob_start();

$pg = basename($_GET['pg']);
if (is_file('views/' . $pg . '.php')) {
  require 'views/' . $pg . '.php';
}

$content = ob_get_clean();

require 'template.php';
```

Any opinions? Thanks.

Comment: If you want it to be truly dynamic, the first step you'll want to do is to leave in only what you want in `$_GET['pg']` for a valid filename. So if you only have views that include letters and numbers, only allow letters and numbers and remove everything else. Also, you'll want to handle an error.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a good idea. About the error handling, the code I posted is just simplified for demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

Wise idea is to write your own array with whitelisted files that can be included. After that, check your `$_GET['pg']` against array via `in_array()`

Comment: I don't know that the OP *has* to, but it would be a wise idea. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But suppose I don't... what are some possible vulnerabilities that could bite me in the ass because of it?

Comment: @Ricky: yes, without it, anybody can just do some bad kind of things.

Comment: Let's say they pass in "../../../../some_other_folder/some_script_they_shouldnt_run", then the best case scenario is that gibberish is printed out. Worst case scenario is that they're able to create a situation where something very bad happens.

Comment: @JeffDay: you didn't mention OP