# jQuery .appendTo() on a <ul> not working

Tags: jquery

A friend helped me with this code.  It works perfect in HTML without jQTouch or JQM.  When put in JQM the details section is not showing up on the next page.  What am I doing wrong?

This is my jQuery mobile outlay. Very simple just trying to get the details page (Pagethree) to show up.  Currently it reverts back to the first page but the url is listed properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "COMBINED.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('MEMBERS').each(function(){
                 /* 
                 * set up list page
                 * gather all variables and format into single variable
                 * for ease of editing
                 */
                var thisID = 'DETAILSPAGE'+$(this).find('ID').text();
                var FIRSTNAME = $(this).find('FIRSTNAME').text()
                var LASTNAME = $(this).find('LASTNAME').text()
                var PARTY = $(this).find('PARTY').text()
                var DISTRICT = $(this).find('DISTRICT').text()
                var TITLE = $(this).find('TITLE').text()
                var THISMEMBER = FIRSTNAME +' '
                        + LASTNAME +'<br />'
                        + TITLE +'-District '+ DISTRICT +', '
                        + PARTY;
                $('<li></li>').html('<a href="#'+thisID+'">'+THISMEMBER+'</a>').appendTo('#LIST');
                /* set up details page */
                var EMAIL = $(this).find('EMAIL').text();
                var OCCUPATION = $(this).find('OCCUPATION').text();
                var EDUCATION = $(this).find('EDUCATION').text();
                var THISMEMBERDETAIL = '<strong>'+FIRSTNAME+' '+LASTNAME+'</strong><br />'
                        + EMAIL+'<br />'
                        + OCCUPATION+'<br />'
                        + EDUCATION;
                $('<a class="memberInfo" name="'+thisID+'"></a>').html(THISMEMBERDETAIL).appendTo('#DETAILS');
            });
        }
    });
    /* toggle function */
    $('a').live('click', function(){
        /* get rid of the pound sign */
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var details = href.substring(1);
        /* if any previous member info was showing, hide it */
        $('.memberInfo').hide();
        /* show the current member info */
        $('a[name="'+details+'"]').show();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.memberInfo {
    /* start with all member info hidden */
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="b" >
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">     
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#LISTPAGE">Page Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Page Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Page Four</a></li>
        </ul>             
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>    
<div data-role="page" id="LISTPAGE">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="LIST"></ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
   </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="DETAILSPAGE">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Three</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" >
        <ul data-role="listview" id="DETAILS"></ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to [cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement) those `$(this)` calls, and maybe do some chaining.

Comment: @dianeinfloria: Jared wasn't offering that as an answer.  He was offering that as a way of writing better/faster code.

Comment: Sorry . I am just getting very desperate.  He spread it out for me so I could understand the process.

Answer (score 0):

#DETAILS is a ul in your html, so will need to wrap your anchor tag in li elements.

Try by replacing

`$('<a class="memberInfo" name="'+thisID+'"</a>').html(THISMEMBERDETAIL).appendTo('#DETAILS');`

with

`$('<li><a class="memberInfo" name="'+thisID+'"></a></li>').html(THISMEMBERDETAIL).appendTo('#DETAILS');`

Answer (score 0):

Changed this and it worked!
        $('').html(THISMEMBERDETAIL).appendTo('#DETAILS');

thanks to Jay Blanchard and his awesome book Applied Jquery!

Answer (score 0):

The line you have in your question is saying, "create an anchor element, then put all the HTML from `THISMEMBERDETAIL` inside of it, then add it to `#DETAILS`".

```
$('<a class="memberInfo" name="'+thisID+'"></a>').html(THISMEMBERDETAIL).appendTo('#DETAILS');
```

The line in your answer is saying, "create an empty string, then replace it with the HTML from `THISMEMBERDETAIL`, then add it to `#DETAILS`". This is totally different from what the code in your question is saying, since it's not adding an `<a>` to `#DETAILS`.

```
$('').html(THISMEMBERDETAIL).appendTo('#DETAILS');
```

So if what you really wanted was what you're saying in your answer, a more concise way to do it is:

```
$('#DETAILS').append( THISMEMBERDETAIL );
```