# jQuery - Tying function to selector without an event?

Tags: jquery

I am just learning how to define a function and call it back later.
I am stuck trying to define 'this' in my function without using an event.

```
function slide() {
    var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt"); 
    var imgTitle = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); 
    var imgDesc = $(this).find('.block').html();  
    var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height(); 

    $(.active); 
    $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250 ,
                function() { 
                    $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85,  marginBottom: "0" }, 250 ); 
                    $(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt}); 
                }
            );
     }
   });
```

On line 6 you will see '$(.active); ' and this is where I want to select the class active and then apply the following function to it. Normally I used to setting this up on a click or something so I am unsure how to impliment it.

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks

Here is a js fiddle where you can see the big picture:
http://jsfiddle.net/wzQj6/21/

Comment: You're better off caching all those `$(this)`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See lines 3-4 in code below for how to cache your `.active` elements for reuse (and then use that instead of `this`!):

```
function slide() {

    //cache all .active elements for reuse
    var actives = $(".active");

    //use the new 'actives' variable instead of 'this'
    var imgAlt = actives.find('img').attr("alt"); 
    var imgTitle = actives.find('a').attr("href"); 
    var imgDesc = actives.find('.block').html();  
    var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height(); 

    //$(.active); -- not sure what you were doing with this :p
    $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250 ,
                function() { 
                    $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85,  marginBottom: "0" }, 250 ); 
                    $(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt}); 
                }
            );
     }
   });
```

Cheers!

Comment: You don't want to use `$(actives)`; `actives` is already a jQuery object, so you can just do `actives.find...`, etc.

Comment: wow, that totally did the trick. That is such a useful thing to know. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling a function, the `this` inside its scope (also called the context) is normally the object that owns and calls the said function. (i.e. with `foo.bar()`, inside `bar()`, `this == foo` normally.)

In Javascript, if you want to call a function AND specify what the function context is, you can use the `call` method like so:

```
bar.call(foo);
// inside bar, this == foo, even if foo wasn't the owner / caller of the function
```

You haven't posted the code for the function that you actually want to call, so I can't comment on whether or not this is the (most) correct way for you to do it, but from what I understand, this should work for you.

```
// take note, also, that your syntax for selecting .active is incorrect.
// you should be passing in a string.
var active_elements = $('.active');
some_function.call(active_elements);
```

Comment: I've posted a JS fiddle in the description to give it some context, thanks for your answer:) I'm trying to process it. I'm not a strong object oriented programmer....yet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you're looking for a way to call functions (jQuery methods too) on a scope, namely javascript context, that you prepare separatedly. If so, here's my code example and explanations.

```
var el = $('.active');
$.fn.animate.call(el, options, timeout, function() { 
  var active = this;
  // do whatever you need
});
```

1. jQuery animate function is defined in a jQuery.prototype namespace which is also a jQuery.fn.
2. There are two ways to call a function on a side context. They are `apply` and `call`. You may check out the difference between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply).

I hope I helped you.