# Rough Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Anyone know why the animation is rough (doesn't really animate) on this bit of jquery?

```
$('.close').click(function() {
    $('.hidden-content').fadeOut('fast', function (){
        $('.serv-button').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Basically when you click on the close button a ".hidden-content" should fade out and the "serv-button"'s should fade in. But instead they just appear and do no fade. Here is my working example, it's on the services section:

http://www.hdesignonline.com/qdup/

Basically I need the content to fade out exactly how it fades in...

Comment: a hidden div should fade out? what's the benefit of this?

Comment: The services section doesn't seem to load on the link?

Comment: The hidden div is actually the ".hidden-content" and toggles from visible to hidden. Sorry for the mistype

Comment: You're duping IDs and have 20+ other errors you may want to fix first: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hdesignonline.com%2Fqdup%2F%23services&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: You need to [*cache your selectors*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's fading each individual block. If you made a wrapper to go around all of them, and had that fade instead of the individual blocks, it would end up much smoother.