# Where should I store jQuery data for html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To better learn jquery I decided to write a plugin that creates a [gallery collage effect](https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus) like google+. Here's an [example](http://www.devurl.co.uk/collagePlus/).

I want to trigger it again on resizing the html element that contains the images. Part of the problem I'm having is that I need to store the original image size in order to recalculate the image sizes to make them fit.

I don't know where to store and how to retrieve those original image sizes. Full plugin is linked above, but I'll put a summary here.

```
;(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.collagePlus = function( options ) {

        var settings = $.extend( 
            //... 
            'images'          : $('img', $(this))
            //... 
        );

        return this.each(function() {
            settings.images.each(function(index){
                //... 

                /*
                * get the current image size
                */
                var w = (typeof $(this).data().width != 'undefined') ? $(this).data().width : $(this).width();
                var h = (typeof $(this).data().height != 'undefined') ? $(this).data().height : $(this).height();

                /*
                * store the original size for resize events
                */
                $(this).attr( "data-width" , w  );
                $(this).attr( "data-height" , h  ); 
                //... Do some other stuff
                }
            );
        });
    }
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Not sure but aren't you using .data() the wrong way? I always set data like: `$(this).data("height", h);` and retrieve it like: `$(this).data("height");`
And I am quite sure, after setting the height data attribute, it will not be undefined next time you will retrieve it.

Comment: @Lumocra that seems to be the problem, yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) wrong. When you pass 1 parameter to the `.data` function, it returns the value for the given key. When you pass 2 parameters, `.data` will set the value for that key.

This block:

```
//get the current image size
var w = (typeof $(this).data().width != 'undefined') ? $(this).data().width : $(this).width();
var h = (typeof $(this).data().height != 'undefined') ? $(this).data().height : $(this).height();
```

Should be:

```
var $this = $(this); //caching your selector
if (!$this.data('width')) //if this element doesn't have a width stored
    $this.data('width', $this.width()); //stores currently computed width
if (!$this.data('height')) //repeat
    $this.data('height', $this.height());
```

And of course, to retrieve the data later:

```
alert($this.data('width')) //alerts currently stored width
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/LE24f/2/)

You can also store an object in the `.data` passing a map of properties:

```
if (!$(this).data('size'))
    $(this).data('size', { width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height() });
```

Now `width` and `height` are properties of the object stored in the `.data('size')`, which can retrieved with:

```
alert($(this).data('size').width);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/LE24f/1/)

For the sake of simplicity, I'd primarily go with the first option. However the second one looks tidier. Choose whichever you find more readable and maintainable.

Comment: thanks, that worked. ```var $this = $(this);``` why are you caching the selector? Is that something I should do?

Comment: Yes. Generally, if you use $(this) more than once, you should cache it in a variable. The prefix "$" helps in recognizing the value of the variable as an jQuery wrapped object.

Comment: @ed209 This is a micro-optimization, I'm looking for Jared's `$(this) vs $this` question which is a good reference. +1 @Wolfram, Also, this way you don't create a new jQuery object every time you reference `$this`. Re-using the selectors improves performance.

Comment: @ed209 Here, [found it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5724400/1331430). The question which enlightened me into using selectors caching. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Wolfram, writing code directly in the answer box when I'm hours past my sleep time tends to generate some stupid mistakes. Fixed the Fiddle now as well. `=]`

Comment: Know that feeling. Also great: writing answers on a phone with non-english Auto-Correct. You can be wide awake and it still manages to get you to rewrite every single word. Also: first non-reviewed edit (2,000 rep). You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

On the server side, you could store data for HTML elements in [`data-*` attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) and get it via jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function (since [jQuery 1.4.3](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/16/jQuery-143-released/), which also changed the general behaviour of that function as noted in the docs). You are setting attributes in your plugin, but at that point, you can just store the original width and height in the `data` object like this:

```
$(this).data( "data-width", w );
$(this).data( "data-height", h );
```

Using the `.data()` function returns the data no matter if it is stored as `data-` attribute in your HTML or if it is contained in jQuery's `data` object attached to the element. You are already using the `.data()` function without any arguments, which [returns the complete `data` object of the matched elements](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.data), also with data from the HTML attributes and from jQuery's `data` object. This works but you could just get the saved `width` and `height` by calling it like this:

```
$(this).data("width");
$(this).data("height");
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention that `.data()` also retrieves the initial value set in the markup, this is worth of a +1. Just note that, OP is storing the *computed* width with the `.width()` client-side, which may vary from actual image size if there are CSS rules that may affect it (namely % dimensions, variable parent dimensions etc.), which are harder to account for server-side and may have an undesired effect otherwise.