# Should I combine jQuery selectors into variables for better performance?

Tags: jquery, performance, variables, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does using $this instead of $(this) provide a performance enhancement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement)

So I am creating a theater like photo gallery that takes up the entire screen, I change the sizes of the divs and Images depending on the window size. So to do this I have been using:

```
function setSizes()
{
var theaterHeight = $(".theater-wrapper").height();
var theaterWidth = $(".theater-wrapper").width();
}

$(window).on("resize", window, function() {
        setSizes();
    });
```

That's basically what I am doing to select the elements in order to get the dimensions to set the heights and widths and such, however window resize does get a bit laggy, and I do end up having quite a few selectors and changing quite a few divs and images all in this one function, and also sometimes the initial call doesn't work properly, or vice versa. So my question is would comibining the selectors result in better performance and such?

like:

```
var $theaterWrapper = $(".theater-wrapper");

var theaterHeight = $theaterWrapper.height();
var theaterWidth = $theaterWrapper.width();
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it or test it with a site like jsperf?

Comment: Yes you should, plus you type less.

Comment: Okay thanks, and i used that website j08691 and in this case it turns out the second way is about 20% faster. cheers.

Comment: The IDE I use (PhpStorm) warns whenever it sees you use the same jQuery selector multiple times in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JSPerf that you can either use as is or modify to more closely match your specific case:

http://jsperf.com/combined-jquery-selectors

In my browser (Chrome on a Mac), your original version runs about 4% slower than your suggested optimization.  On my iPhone using Safari, it's about 6% slower. But on Firefox on my Mac, it's a 14% difference.

So it would appear that your proposed improvement is in fact better.

Comment: Ah yes, well I did my own test a few minutes ago myself, but I just ran the one you linked and I got 16% faster. (Firefox 15 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion)

Comment: One thing that no one mentioned is that jQuery has internal caching of the last used selector, so mix a couple more selectors in there and you'll notice a higher % difference.

Comment: I too see a much bigger effect on Firefox. Will amend the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it does, because  you are traversing the DOM **one time less** in the latter case..

It is always a better option to save the selector and store it if the selector you use is a static one...

Also it leads to smaller and leaner code.