# jQuery Selectors and $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an interesting selector statement:

```
$("span#dateofbirth").bind('click', function() {
  $("span#dateofbirth>form>input.inplace_field").blur();
  $("span#dateofbirth>form>input.inplace_field").removeClass("inplace_value");
  $("span#dateofbirth>form>input.inplace_field").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
  $("span#dateofbirth>form>input.inplace_field").addClass("inplace_value");
  $("span#dateofbirth>form>input.inplace_field").focus();
});
```

It was actually inserted by someone else, to make the jQuery UI datepicker work with an Edit-in-Place plugin. It appears to be more of a hack/band-aid than anything. But it works.

I want to continue working with it, but I'd like to modify it to be more global for any element with a Date.

So, I gave the spans a class of `.datepicker`

But, it doesn't quite work, since the bind prefers the specific ID, to localize to that element.

Is there a way around this, perhaps using the `$(this)`, in conjunction with the rest of the selector statement?

Perhaps something along the line of?

```
$("span.datepicker").bind('click', function() { 

  $(this+">form>input.inplace_field").blur();

});
```

Comment: Please [my question on caching jQuery objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement). Note, in many circumstances the `element#id` is unnecessary, as `#id` is all that's needed. I think that jQuery will optimize and discard the `span` anyhow for performance reasons. However, avoid reselecting the same selector repetitively (cache instead) and understand the impact of the selector sequence and you'll have much better overall performance in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.find()`

```
$(this).find(">form>input.inplace_field")
```

**OR**

```
$(">form>input.inplace_field" , this)  // Provide a context to search in
```

**JS**

```
$("span#dateofbirth").bind('click', function() {
  $(">form>input.inplace_field" , this).blur()
          .removeClass("inplace_value")
          .datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'})
          .addClass("inplace_value")
          .focus();
});
```

You should `chain` or `cache` the selectors to reduce the times you query the **DOM.**

Answer (score 2):

Selectors are ordinary strings.

You're trying to write

```
$(this).find(">form>input.inplace_field")
```

Answer (score 0):

The child selector `>` is now deprecated in jQuery selectors (still OK in CSS).

You should be using something along the following lines :

```
$(".datepicker").on('click', function() {
  $(this).children("form").children("input.inplace_field").blur()
          .removeClass("inplace_value")
          .datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'})
          .addClass("inplace_value")
          .focus();
});
```