# Is JavaScript wrapper object creation lightweight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

[image: JQuery Wrapper Performance Test]

This performance test shows that, there is almost no difference between code with creation of jquery wrapper object and code without jquery wrapper object creation ( In second case wrapper object is stored in a variable named d and not created again and again).

Do you think these results are correct? Is JQuery-Wrapper actually extremely lightweight?

Here is the link to JSPerf. http://jsperf.com/jquery-wrapper-performance

Comment: I'm afraid you are doing nothing in those tests

Comment: Your "test" isn't very well designed. If what you're referring to is the performance improvement when caching a jQuery object instead of requerying, in certain situations, [yes, it does matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement). In what you showed, no. It'd be negligible.

Comment: @JaredFarrish the test dosen't show a difference for a different reason than you think. And yes, it's flawed.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Sure, that was a good catch by Alexander. Boneheaded for sure, but we've all been there, done that. However, the flaws still outweigh what practical takeaway due to the way the test subjects were structured and so on. I'm in the habit of caching relentlessly, but I realize it's excessive optimization about... 70% of the time. But I've gotten bit really, really hard when it went wrong (which is where the question came from). in reality, the latter `div` would probably never be used in such a way, and in any event, would be about 7-% of the time harmless inefficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to run the function `updateFunctions` in those tests, so those tests are nothing more than mere function definitions.

You can start seeing the differences in this [fixed test suite](http://jsperf.com/jquery-wrapper-performance/2) where the actual code is running.

[image: jquery-wrapper-performance]

Comment: I suggest removing the function call entirely: http://jsperf.com/jquery-wrapper-performance/3

Comment: It's still interesting to observe that the first function gets defined marginally faster than the second one.

Comment: Actually this answer, answered two things, 1). How to use jsperf properly and 2). There is actually a heavy performance difference.

Comment: @JanDvorak, Yes there is more text in first function.

Comment: @SunnyShah try running the test with ID selectors. They should be faster (less difference)

Comment: It's a frivolous difference. Who in their right mind would start off with a `$('<div')` query? Why was `.css()` called? Meh.

Comment: @SunnyShah - It's not that "heavy" in this case. Those differences, especially after Jan's modification, are ignorable in real life situations. Ahd it's hard and time-consuming to design useful test cases, so don't beat yourself up too much.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Well I am coming from embedded programming background, Compilers are much more smarter there. Just wanted to make sure that JS JIT just does not ignore my statement. Trust me, GCC is extremely smart in compile time optimizations.

Comment: s/more smarter/more agressive/

Comment: @SunnyShah - The new JS interpreters (I don't know if I'd call them JITs) store code routes by trace and reuse alot of stuff now. So it's entirely *possible* that in the first "heavy" example, Chrome is storing that reference and reusing it. That's why I say it's hard and time-consuming to build effective test cases. There's all kinds of ifs, ands or butts to factor first.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I believe V8 performs proper compilation to native code, not just of the linear segments of code. That's what makes `eval` sooo expensive - the need to compile (or interpret) a piece of code.

Comment: @SunnyShah - You might read up on [SpiderMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey_(JavaScript_engine)) or Chrome's V8 engine enhancements, it's really kinda wild. Whoever wrote that Wikipedia article felt confident enough to call it a JIT, so maybe JS has made it over the hump. Also, check out the Common.js  components and proposals as well as and CoffeeScript development if you want to find out where the language is going.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Of course, that's what trace routing is about. It's a specialized form of compilation. So I think they're all more or less doing "proper" compilation (but is it truly a JIT?) with the "pathway" to the most referenced or sought after code being compiled at first read to be as efficient as possible. I don't know enough about the internals to say, but I have a feeling there's an angle to V8's method that  doesn't quite get us to fully compiled code in the traditional sense (C).