# ID or Class for textarea?

Tags: php, jquery

I was working on a tooltip from scratch. The code for the tooltip has been added below.

Issue with following code:

The tooltip fades in and out on focussing or blurring on the text-area but the problem is,  all the tooltips (tooltips corresponding to all the elements) fade in and out simultaneously.

The second issue is that the value of the text-area is same in all the tooltips which is the value of the first text-area.

**PHP**

```
<?php for($j; $j<5; $j++) { ?>
<tr>
<td style="position:relative"><?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($PackageDeal,"package[$j][1]") ; ?>
    <div style="color:#0D776e;font-size:15px;font-family:calibri;padding:1%;margin:0 0.5%;;word-wrap:break-word;display:none;z-index:100;width:200px;mion-height:25px;position:absolute;top:30px;"></div>
</td>
</tr> 
<?php }?>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
        $("textarea").focus(function(){
            $("td div").fadeIn(400).css({"background-color":"#E7F1F0","border":"1px solid #86BBB6"});
            $("td div").html($("textarea").val());
        });
        $("textarea").blur(function(){
            $("td div").fadeOut(400).css({"background-color":"#E7F1F0","border":"1px solid #86BBB6"});

        });
        $("textarea").keyup(function(){
            $("td div").html($("textarea").val());
            });
            });
</script>
```

The issue is that I'm using this tooltip in a **PHP** *for* loop and I tried variety of ways so that the tooltip is functional. I need to ask whether I should keep an Id / Class for the tooltip (div element) and for the text-areas so that the text shown is different in all and all of them don't show up simultaneously. Also I would like to know whether this is a jquery, php or html related issue. Thanks in Advance!

P.S. the tooltip works fine for single element.

Comment: This isn't a PHP problem. You're overselecting with `td div`; literally, on `.focus` and `.blur` you're getting *every* `div` in a `td` *on the page* and running the effect on each. You have to be more specific, for instance `$(this).parent()...` or `$(this).siblings()...`, etc.

Comment: And, personally, on the `div` I would use a class to *group* them as belonging to a type of element that all have the same or similar behavior, styling, etc. `id` attributes are meant to be *specific* to a single element, so do not use `id`s to group when you want to `class`.

Comment: Can you please be a more specific?

Comment: Sumit, see my sample and the [jsFiddle working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QtWTK/) linked in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your page would have a lot of `<td><div></div></td>`s from generated HTML (by PHP), and all matches `td div`, all of them would show if you were to call `$('td div').//so on`

So you need to specify which one you want to show, and in your case you want the one near to the element that is `focused` or `blurred`. jQuery is good at that.

```
$("textarea").focus(function(){
    var targetArea = $(this);
    targetArea.siblings('div').fadeIn(400).css({"background-color":"#E7F1F0","border":"1px solid #86BBB6"})
        .html(targetArea.val());
});
```

Also, as per @joeltine answer, you also need to show only the html for that textarea too, so also use the same `$(this)` in your `html` call parameter.

For performance, you may want to chain them together and cache `$(this)` to a variable as above too - the `$` constructor is expensive.

And one more thing, you seem to set `css` when it fades in and fades out, but they are not necessary - when you can set it in a `css` file instead. Their style can't be seen if you set it beforehand and they are not shown (by `display: none`) anyway.

```
$("textarea").focus(function(){
    var targetArea = $(this);
    targetArea.siblings('div').fadeIn(400).html(targetArea.val());
});
```

and in CSS:

```
/* You really want to apply this css to all "td div" for this one! */
td div {
   background-color: #E7F1F0;
   border: 1px solid #86BBB6;
   /* More styles for tooltips, such as display: none; position: relative; etc... */
}
```

Comment: Why use the event target and not just `this`?

Comment: `this` works, but I feel `event.target` is more readable. Anyway, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `class` for your `textarea`, i.e. `myTxtArea` and use `$(this)` like

```
$("textarea.myTxtArea").focus(function(){
   var el=$(this);
   el.closest("td").find("div").fadeIn(400).css({"background-color":"#E7F1F0","border":"1px solid #86BBB6"});
   el.closest("td").find("div").html(el.val());
});
```

[**An Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8yxj/1/).

Comment: Would the functionality differ if I use your code with a difference that I don't create a class for textarea?

Comment: @SumitGera, You can use it without a class too. The class is being used to use only some specific `textareas` so other `textareas` on the same page wouldn't get the same functionality.

Comment: One note, please don't repeat `$(this)` this is actually doing a lot of work behind the scenes by re-creating a jquery object.  Just cache it and re-use it `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: @joeltine - I [certainly agree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724400/does-using-this-instead-of-this-provide-a-performance-enhancement), to a point. `$('td div')` is *way* more harmful than repeated `$(this)`, since at least `this` refers to a DOM element. It's worth mentioning for Sumit, but in the example will not have a detrimental side effect on performance.

Comment: Not detrimental, in this example, true.  It's just better to get in the habit.  It's such a free-win for performance, you might as well just do it.

Comment: I think, in this case, `var el=-$(this)` and `$(this)` doesn't decrease performance because both are object references, but caching the object reference in a variable saves some typing, IMO.

Comment: @joeltine - I'm certainly guilty of probably over-referencing, but it's more a side-effect (*now*) of code structure (in case reuse later is necessary). I'm actually "guilty" of it (ha ha, right?) in my answer, although I initially did it to clean up the code formatting before I reordered the callbacks as standalone functions. It's just... not a *rule*, per se, but good to know.

Answer (score 1):

@luiges90 addressed your one issue... and I'll also mention the reason your tooltips are all showing the same value (the value in the first text area on the page) is because your selector `$('textarea')` is selecting ALL the textareas on the page.  When you call .val() on that, by default, it only returns the value of the first element in the collection.  So in short, in your focus event just use something like this:

```
$("textarea").focus(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings('div').fadeIn(400).css({"background-color":"#E7F1F0","border":"1px solid #86BBB6"})
        .html($this.val());
});
```

Comment: Making an arbitrary reference in this manner is not very useful if you're going to chain everything. There's a time and place for everything... `;)`

Comment: Notice I use $this twice.  Once for the chain and once for $this.val().

Comment: Ahh, very true. Still not a performance enhancement in the application itself ([`this.value` gets no love?](http://jsfiddle.net/fuFuT/1/)), but I am guilty of doing it under "other motives".

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was talking about:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea class="editable">This is a texarea.</textarea>
        <div class="uneditable"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    ... More rows ...
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea class="editable">This is a texarea.</textarea>
        <div class="uneditable"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

Note the use of `textarea.editable`, `text.uneditable`, `$(this).siblings('.uneditable')`, and `$(this).next('div.uneditable')`. The `div.uneditable` is a little gratuitous here, but I offer it as a demonstration of overselecting (in case there were also a `span.uneditable` or whatever *next* in flow with the `div.uneditable`...).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $editable = $('textarea.editable');

  $editable
      .focus(focus)
      .blur(blur)
      .keyup(keyup);

  function focus() {
    $(this).siblings(".uneditable").fadeIn(400).css({
      "background-color": "#E7F1F0",
      "border": "1px solid #86BBB6"
    })
    .html($(this).val());
  }

  function blur() {
    $(this).siblings('.uneditable').fadeOut(400).css({
      "background-color": "#E7F1F0",
      "border": "1px solid #86BBB6"
    });
  }

  function keyup() {
    $(this).next("div.uneditable").html($(this).val());
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fuFuT/

Comment: Thank you @Jared for the effort.You are quite close, but the textboxes shift downwards when the tooltip appears. Anyways thanks alot.

Comment: @SumitGera - Note, it was demonstration on the selectors I had mentioned in the comment, so I wasn't concerned with the actual tooltip functionality. That's I commented that part of the class definition out.

Comment: Yeah. That I actually presumed. Thanks for the demo.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why all of them go at the same time, is because you select all of them, `$("textarea")` returns all matching elements.

To prevent that behaviour, create this (I didn't include the event functions for readability)

```
// Do things for each matching elements, separately
$("textarea").each(function() {
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).keyup();
});
```

As for the id / class for the tooltip: it is generally better to keep the CSS external, so in that case, giving the tooltips a CSS class would be better.

Comment: The problem is that he is selecting every `$("td div")` on focus and blur. How does this fix that problem?